# Parsing a log file into CSV format

Tags: java, parsing, matlab, csv, logging

Im trying to develop a small bit of code that will help me delimit a log file that has stored a large number of trace routes to different IP's that were sent over a period of week.

Im hoping to split them using a '--- START ---' and '--- END ---' tag at the begining and the end of each trace route. Example is as followed:

```
--- START ---
Mon Mar 12 22:45:05 GMT 2012
traceroute to xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  xxxxxxx (xxxxx)  1.085 ms  1.662 ms  2.244 ms
2  xxxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)  0.792 ms  0.782 ms  0.772 ms
3  xxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxx)  8.545 ms  9.170 ms  9.644 ms
4  etc
5  etc
--- END ---
--- START ---
Mon Mar 12 22:45:05 GMT 2012
traceroute to xxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  139.222.0.1 (xxxxxxxxx)  0.925 ms  1.318 ms  1.954 ms
2  10.0.0.1 (xxxxxxxx)  0.345 ms  0.438 ms  0.496 ms
3  172.16.0.34 (xxxxxxxxx)  0.830 ms  2.553 ms  0.809 ms
4 etc
5 etc
6 etc
--- END ---
```

Can anyone give me a hand into how this would be done, in matlab or java... I'm also trying to count the amount of hops each trace route makes. That being the number given before the --- END --- tag is thrown...

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: Just look at the first letter on every line. If it is in CAPS: it is the first line with the date on it. If it is lowercase (traceroute) it is the second line. If it is numeric: it is one of the "hop" lines.

Answer (score 2):

Quick 'n dirty example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main
{
  private static class Record
  {
    public Date date;

    public String to;
    public int hops;
    public int packetSize;

    public String toString()
    {
      return date + " ::: " + to + ", " + hops + " hops, "
        + packetSize + " bytes";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("input.txt")));

    Record currentRecord = null;
    ArrayList<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = s.nextLine();

      if ("--- START ---".equals(line)) {
        currentRecord = new Record();

      } else if ("--- END ---".equals(line)) {
        list.add(currentRecord);
        currentRecord = null;

      } else if (currentRecord.date == null) {
        currentRecord.date = new SimpleDateFormat(
          "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(line);

      } else if (line.startsWith("traceroute to ")) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
          "traceroute to ([^ ]+) [^,]+, ([^ ]+) hops max, ([^ ]+) byte packets");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        if (m.matches()) {
          currentRecord.to = m.group(1);
          currentRecord.hops = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
          currentRecord.packetSize = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        }
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
      System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Tue Mar 13 04:15:05 GMT+05:30 2012 ::: 203.98.69.105, 30 hops, 60 bytes
Tue Mar 13 04:15:05 GMT+05:30 2012 ::: 62.193.36.27, 30 hops, 60 bytes
```

I'm pointing you in a bunch of different directions (`Scanner`, `Pattern`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.). For the individual "gateway" items, you could also use `String.split()` using `"  "` (two spaces) as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im also trying to show the number of hops each trace route each has made, im finding it difficult as it doesnt state the last trace route. Instead its the last trace before the '--- END ---' line is shown. 

How would i go about telling the code to find the last trace before the final END line? Then id be able to print the amount of hops its made...

Comment: @FredBones As I've stated in the post, I've pointed you in the right direction by introducing you to a bunch of classes that you can use to parse the text. Hint: Add another `else if` block and parse the hop, including the number (which appears first!); update `Record` with an `ArrayList` containing all the hops. I hope you're able to write out the logic yourself.

Comment: Manish, appreciate the help! I havnt used java in a while and have just had to jump back into it so am finding it slightly difficult. Ill take on your advice and get back to you with how well it goes! Cheers!

Comment: Manish, I'm finding it difficult to interpret what is going on in your code. Im trying to make it read every new line of each trace routes but unsure how. If you could get me started by just showing me how to get final hop number it'd be really appreciated...