# Parse a log file and remove unwanted data

Tags: java, regex, csv, pattern-matching

So I have a Log file which gives details on locking and unlocking of nodes. The time and date `18:02:21` and the ID `"ieatrcxb4498-1"` for each node.

```
150: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                    :     Info: Lock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4498-1"
     264: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                   :     Info: Unlock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4498-1"
     268: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                   :     Info: Lock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4496-1"
     382: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                   :     Info: Unlock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4496-1"
     407: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                   :     Info: Lock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4500-1"
     473: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo                   :     Info: Unlock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4500-1"
```

What I want to do is run the log file through my program removing unwanted data and formatting the output to look like, or something close too.

```
Node            Lock        Unlock  
ieatrcxb4498-1  18:02:21                    
ieatrcxb4498-1              18:02:21                
ieatrcxb4500-1  18:02:21        
ieatrcxb4500-1              18:02:21
```

I have a basic program which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762459/parsing-a-log-file-into-csv-format) and adjusted but I am struggling to get it to work properly.

```
public class Main {

    private static class Record
    {

        public String node;
        public Date lock;
        public Date unlock;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Record{" +
                    ", node='" + node + '\'' +
                    ", lock='" + lock + '\'' +
                    ", unlock='" + unlock + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("input.txt")));

        Record currentRecord = null;
        ArrayList<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();

            if ("SHOW_PLAN BEGIN".equals(line)) {
                currentRecord = new Record();

            } else if ("SHOW_PLAN END".equals(line)) {
                list.add(currentRecord);
                currentRecord = null;

            } else if (currentRecord.lock == null) {
                currentRecord.lock = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm:ss").parse(line);

            }else if(currentRecord.unlock == null){
                currentRecord.unlock = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm:ss").parse(line);
            }
            else if (line.startsWith("traceroute to ")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                        "monitor ([^ ]+) [^,]+, ([^ ]+) hops max, ([^ ]+) byte packets");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

                if (m.matches()) {
                    currentRecord.node = m.group(1);
//                    currentRecord.lock = m.
//                    currentRecord.unlock = m.group(3);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the line around all white space before you start creating your Record object. I would suggest creating the object with 3 variables, its time, its state (Locked/Unlocked) and its ID.

```
public class Record
{
    String time;
    String state;
    String ID;
}
```

Then you can simply split around the space and take the certain indexes that contain the information you need like so

```
    String line = "150: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo   :    Info: Lock VCS on node \"ieatrcxb4498-1\"";

    String[] pieces = line.split("\\s+");

    Record obj = new Record();
    obj.time = pieces[2];
    obj.state = pieces[7];
    obj.id = pieces[11].replaceAll("\"", "");
```

All that's left to do is format the output which can easily be done using the [sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699878/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-two-columns-to-the-console-in-java) function like so

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "Node", "Lock", "Unlock");
```

Now you just loop through all your objects in your list and check the state of the object

```
for(Record obj : list)
{
    if(obj.state.equals("Lock"))
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", obj.ID, obj.time, "");
    else
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", obj.ID, "", obj.time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will look at it soon and get back to you.